# Configuring MySQL to run on a public IP

Tags: mysql, ip, localhost, public

I'm having trouble getting MySQL to install on a public IP. The installation is on a public server so public access isn't blocked. However it installs as localhost and I can't find out how to change that. Does anyone know how?

The server is a Windows 2008 machine.

Thanks

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on either [sf] or [dba.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just comment out

```
bind-address = ...
```

in your config file or specify a particular network interface you want your mysql server to listen to.

And don't forget to restart mysql after that.